# com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFException: Corcorrupt input data, block did not start with 2 byte signature ('ZV') followed by type byte, 2-byte length)

Tags: apache-spark

I am using Spark 1.3.1 and getting below error while running in spark-client mode.

om.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: com.ning.compress.lzf.LZFException: Corcorrupt input data, block did not start with 2 byte signature ('ZV') followed by type byte, 2-byte length)